# How to add a raw PostgreSQL function to a query builder join in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM on a NestJS service written in TypeScript.

I am trying to use PostgreSQL's `jsonb_each` function as a table in a join to create a query similar to this:
`select * from customers c left join jsonb_each(c.some_json_column) as d`

When I put `jsonb_each(c.some_json_column)` in TypeORM's `leftJoin` function, TypeORM wraps it with double quotes, which forces PostgreSQL to think that I am trying to access a table named `jsonb_each(c.some_json_column)` and PostgreSQL throws an error.

How can I force TypeORM to use `jsonb_each(c.some_json_column)` as a raw value in the leftJoin function, and not wrappiwrapg it with double-quotes?